# Run Microsoft Edge in a hidden window

Tags: powershell

I have a need to open one or more webpages in Microsoft Edge and keep them in the cache for quick access while also being in hidden windows that my enterprise users will not see in their taskbar so that they will not accidentally close them. In the course of their workday, users will access these pages in browser windows they will open themselves but the hidden webpages will be cached so the data will be available quickly to the users as they need it.

I have tried using the "Start microsoft-edge: -WindowStyle hidden" command but Edge only starts up in a normal window.

Please advise how to do this with powershell in WIndows 10.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Good question. Tough since Edge prefers being launched as a Windows "app". Calling `microsoft-edge:` (with the trailing colon) starts the "app". The `MicrosoftEdge.exe` in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` won't open by launching it directly. I wonder if you'll be able to handle running Edge as a service. Might also work running it as another user so it appears hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I have run it as a service using NSSM.exe (Non Sucking Service Manager) but it still shows a window. I want to try your other suggestion: running it as another user. How should I do that?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting Edge to run as another user. This is usually easiest set from the Task Scheduler. Create a task that runs notepad.exe as another account, execute it, and `Get-Process notepad -IncludeUserName` shows the process. Create a task using any of the various ways of launching Edge and Edge doesn't appear to launch.